# Visual Studio Code complaining about #!/usr/bin/env node

Tags: node.js, editor, visual-studio-code

Wondering why [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is complaining about `#!/usr/bin/env node`

Any pointer on how to resolve the error would be helpful.

[image: screenshot]

---

### Steps to reproduce

[Setup code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup) and [install node and npm](https://nodejs.org/), if not already done.

Then follow the below instructions

```
npm install -g express
npm install -g express-generator

express awesome-app
cd awesome-app
code .
```

Open up `bin/www` file in editor, check out the squiggly line below the `#!/usr/bin/env node` line.

Visual Studio Code automatically detected the syntax to be `JavaScript`.

[image: screencast - gif]

**PS: I am using Visual Studio Code for Mac Os X**

Comment: Define "complaining." Is it simply underlining the line or is it actually preventing you from debugging/executing/etc.? That particular line is used on *nix to be able to execute the script directly. On Windows, npm creates `.cmd` files that have that line stripped out.

Comment: squiggly underline, it not preventing the file to be executed in the debug context from the editor. However its visually confusing.

Comment: It looks to me like you're using the wrong type of syntax highlighting for the file you are editing. Try changing changing the syntax VSC is using by clicking on the current one in the bottom right edge of the screen and change it to the type of file you're editing.

Comment: @LoganTegman syntax is properly set to JavaScript, as it should be. Looks like `vscode` is confused with it. Please follow the [instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/nodejs) and open up the file `path/to/bin/www`.

Answer (score 0):

That is something we should have gotten right. Can you detail a little about how you got into this state? Did you create the file newly and only later saved it as JS or changed the type with the drop-down in the lower right?

[image: shebang]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have filed a bug on my end will make sure it's fixed with the next update.

Answer (score 0):

I was using nvm to manage node versions. I worked around this problem by launching VS Code from a shell that has `node` in the path.

`➜  ~ cd Projects/my-project/ 
➜  my-project git:(master) ✗ code .`